Training with a large tensor in TensorFlow framework
I am working with a NumPy (.npy) tensor of size 50000 * 64* 128 * 128 * 1 to train a 3D segmentation model with approximately 30 million trainable parameters. I am using TensorFlow framework and utilizing Google's colab pro+ subscription and still the model is not getting trained and throwing the OOM error.
Is there any way to push the this tensor to the model. Fit() in memory efficient way?
